# What is parallel Query in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I heard a expression somewhere about "Parallel Query" in mongodb.
I was wondering what is it about and how it helps.

I just heard that they can benefit instead of using array for storing temp results.
But i wonder how it works and what is it, because i found nothing on google, maybe it has another name?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/concurrency/

Comment: It's not a mongodb thing but a programming thing. Usually async event driven or threaded processing

Comment: Thanks for the links and explanation ;)

Comment: as @NeilLunn says, it is an extension of the parallel processing paradigm  within programming, however, the concurrency page does not actually talk about this; it in fact talks about something quite different.